# Limit code to one worksheet on workbook activate

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that I need to run on workbook activate event.  I created a module where I saved the code, and call to it on workbook activate event.

The code needs to affect only one worksheet called "Rates", but it affects other worksheets in the workbook as well.

I need to limit the code to this specific worksheet.

The code is below, I know it is not very clean, but seemed to work.

```
Sub Replace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim myuniquevalue As String
Dim nextvalue As String

myuniquevalue = Sheets("Rates").Cells(2, 1).Value & Sheets("Rates").Cells(2, 2).Value

Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(2, 12)).Value = Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(3, 12)).Value

LastRow = Worksheets("Rates").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    nextvalue = Worksheets("Rates").Cells(i, 1).Value &  Worksheets("Rates").Cells(i, 2).Value

    If myuniquevalue <> nextvalue Then
        myuniquevalue = nextvalue
        Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 12)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 1, 6), Cells(i + 1, 12)).Value
    End If
    LastRow = Sheets("Rates").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Next i

LastRow = Worksheets("Rates").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

myuniquevalue = Worksheets("Rates").Cells(LastRow, 1).Value &   Worksheets("Rates").Cells(LastRow, 2).Value & Worksheets("Rates").Cells(LastRow, 3).Value
Range(Cells(LastRow, 10), Cells(LastRow, 12)).Value = Range(Cells(LastRow - 1, 10), Cells(LastRow - 1, 12)).Value

 For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
     nextvalue = Worksheets("Rates").Cells(i, 1).Value & Worksheets("Rates").Cells(i, 2).Value & Worksheets("Rates").Cells(i, 3).Value

    If myuniquevalue <> nextvalue Then
        myuniquevalue = nextvalue

        Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 12)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 1, 10), Cells(i - 1, 12)).Value

     End If

 Next i

fndList = Array("(6 - 12)", "(13 - 24)", "(25 - 36)", "(37 - 61)")
rplcList = Array("12", "24", "36", "48")

Set sht = Worksheets("Rates")
For x = 0 To UBound(fndList)

  'For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: try adding an activation of the sheet.

thisworkbook.sheets("Rates").Activate , perhaps at the start of your script, or the start of the loop

Comment: Which part is affecting the other worksheets? The `Range.Value=Range.Value` lines, the `For x`:`Next x` section, or both?

Answer (score 1):

Move `Set sht = Worksheets("Rates")` to the beginning of your code. Then you can use `sht` to access only the `"Rates"` worksheet's objects without affecting the other sheets in the workbook.

```
Sub Replace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim myuniquevalue As String
Dim nextvalue As String

Set sht = Worksheets("Rates")

myuniquevalue = sht.Cells(2, 1).Value & sht.Cells(2, 2).Value

sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 6), sht.Cells(2, 12)).Value = sht.Range(sht.Cells(3, 6), sht.Cells(3, 12)).Value    

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
nextvalue = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value & sht.Cells(i, 2).Value

If myuniquevalue <> nextvalue Then
    myuniquevalue = nextvalue
    sht.Range(sht.Cells(i, 6), sht.Cells(i, 12)).Value = sht.Range(sht.Cells(i + 1, 6), sht.Cells(i + 1, 12)).Value
End If
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Next i

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

myuniquevalue = sht.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value & sht.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value & sht.Cells(LastRow, 3).Value
sht.Range(sht.Cells(LastRow, 10), sht.Cells(LastRow, 12)).Value = sht.Range(sht.Cells(LastRow - 1, 10), sht.Cells(LastRow - 1, 12)).Value

 For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
 nextvalue = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value & sht.Cells(i, 2).Value & sht.Cells(i, 3).Value

 If myuniquevalue <> nextvalue Then
    myuniquevalue = nextvalue

   sht.Range(sht.Cells(i, 10), sht.Cells(i, 12)).Value = sht.Range(sht.Cells(i - 1, 10), sht.Cells(i - 1, 12)).Value

 End If

 Next i

fndList = Array("(6 - 12)", "(13 - 24)", "(25 - 36)", "(37 - 61)")
rplcList = Array("12", "24", "36", "48")

For x = 0 To UBound(fndList)

  'For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: If you do what @rymerej mentions, you should then be able to add `With sht` just before the initialization of `myuniquevalue` and `End With` after `Next x`. Doing so allows you to drop all of the references to `sht` and instead start each statement with `.Cell` etc. etc. It'll help clean up your code a bit. Also, be sure to add commenting in, for both your sake and others who may come behind you. Besides being a best practice, I promise that you won't regret it.

Comment: Good points. You could also remove `Set sht = Worksheets("Rates")` altogether and just add `With Worksheets("Rates")` where @TotsieMae said to add `With sht`.